# Remove Attribute Set from conditions for Catalog Price Rule

Tags: magento-1.7

Can anyone throw some light on how to remove 'Attribute Set' from conditions  for  "Catalog Price Rule" in the the admin section in a better way.

I can do the following thing.
In the class `Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Product_Abstract`
I comment for attribute_set_id 'Attribute Set'

```
protected function _addSpecialAttributes(array &$attributes)
    {
        $attributes['attribute_set_id'] = Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Attribute Set');
        $attributes['category_ids'] = Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Category');
    }
```

But this is the abstract class so I can't extend this one.

So I need a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets into the curious decision of whether to implement the change **one time** in a superseding class definition, *or* implementing the change **multiple times** in concrete-/sub-classes. There are a few things to consider when deciding how to change core logic:

1. Local change or public module
2. Availability & suitability of events
3. Magento flavor (CE/EE), because of the number of classes extending the main

#1 is something for you answer for yourself - if it is a local change then you have less restrictions on how you implement.

#2 is generally the more extendable, cross-cutting way to get your changes done. In this case, there are none :-(

#3 is where your needs lie. Because there are no events, you are forced to consider the number of rewrites versus a proper core redefinition. For CE install there are 2 subclasses of this abstract class, so I might be inclined to just do a rewrite on those. For an EE install there are 8 subclasses, which I would be loathe to rewrite with such a gross violation of DRY.

Ultimately how you implement a definition change is subject to the criterion of maintainability, and it seems that it is more maintainable to implement this by copying the `Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Product_Abstract` to the local codepool, implementing your change, and stating this in the release notes.

Comment: Nice explanation.However one question. Suppose there is an event attached to a function then, it is better to write an observer than to override it?

Comment: If you are developing a third-arty module, it's imperative. We do mostly local implementations but tend to use observers.